# You do not have the PROCESS privilege at /usr/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 4456, <STDIN> line 1

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-rds, rhel, pt-online-schema-change

I'm experiment with the pt-online-schema-change tool with a MySQL 5.7 database hosted by AWS RDS.  I have gotten past a few different configuration issues and when I run a `dry-run` everything looks good but I get this error immediately when I try and run the command with the `execute` flag.

I'm running this on Amazon Linux 2 which is RHEL 8 based (I believed).  I'm not sure if this is related to my Linux permissions or my database permissions.  I'm running this as root on my workstation and my MySQL user has fairly elevated permissions.

I found a [Percona forum post](https://forums.percona.com/t/pt-online-schema-change-error-line-4320/4505) on this but it's from a long time ago with only one response and the response doesn't provide any concrete advice on how to resolve and I'm not sure the response is valid based on other internet researches about linux process permissions.

Any advice on how to resolve this error?  Do I need to add more permissions for my MYSQL user or something on the linux command line side?

```sh
$ pt-online-schema-change D=my_db,t=my_table,h=my_host.com,u=my_user --alter="drop COLUMN ios_notification_token" --alter-foreign-keys-method="auto" --ask-pass --preserve-triggers --execute
Enter MySQL password: 
You do not have the PROCESS privilege at /usr/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 4456, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Comment: If I recall, you can run `pt-online-schema-change --recursion-method none` and it will not need the PROCESS privilege. But it won't monitor replication lag if you do that.

Comment: Can confirm the above, adding the `--recursion-method none` option allowed my `pt-online-schema-change` command to successfully run without needing to change any database user permissions

Answer (score 2):

I ended up needing to grant additional privileges to the MySQL user being used for the migration by pt-online-schema-change.

Assuming the DB name is `my_db` and the user is `my_user`, running these commands should give the tool the permissions it needs to perform the migration.

```
GRANT PROCESS, SELECT, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO my_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_db`.* TO my_user;
```

Comment: If you are using grant all, the first grant it is not needed